# Нумерация элементов по пути, С#

Tags: c#, алгоритм

У меня есть объекты, соединенные линиями. У каждого объекта я могу получить его координаты (x, y). Мне необходимо пронумеровать эти объекты для примера в следующем порядке (см. рис). С какой стороны подойти к этой проблеме, чтобы ее решить? 
Идея такая: Я выделяю объект(круг) и задаю ему начальный номер, а алгоритм определял что с чем соединяется и пронумеровал следующие за ним элементы по порядку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для того чтобы пронумеровать элементы, вам нужно вначале сформулировать правило нумерации. Обычно вы нумеруете или по координатам (например, чем больше X тем больше номер), или по графу (например начинаете с какого-то нода и нумеруете его соседей "в глубину"). Сочетать оба варианта - проблематично.

Comment: *Но как ее построить имея только данные о расположении объекта?* – информация о связях у вас в каком-то виде имеется же?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению пока нет. Но я думаю, что смогу связать координаты линии и координаты объекта. Я пока пытаюсь понять смысл

Comment: Нумерация по координатам мне кажется не совсем будет корректна, так как например значение Х будет таким же, но значение Y будет отличаться.

Comment: Ну у вас по сути тогда и графа нет никакого. Вопрос не понятен. Как вот вы на своей картинке определили, что у вас ребро между 6 и 7 вершинами, а не, например, между 2 и 7?

Comment: Мне нужно самому задавать, что с чем соединять

Comment: При чем тут тогда алгоритм поиска в глубину? Сконцентрируйтесь на одной задаче и опишите ее подробнее в вопросе. Пока ничего не понятно.

Comment: Откорректировал вопрос, постарался более конкретно описать

Comment: Блин, ну а как определить-то что с чем соединяется? Опишите правила.

Comment: Допустим, линия выходит из центра окружности, значит координаты одной из точек линии будут равны координатам центра окружности, линия соединяется с центром другой окружности, соответственно там тоже координаты будут равны. Получается, что у двух окружностей общая линия, значит они связвны... Я думал в таком ключе

Comment: Вы зачем-то хотите пронумеровать в порядке смежности -- что никак не получается даже на вашем рисунке из-за развилок (3-4, 3-6); учитывая, что всё в любом случае начинается с того, что как-то придётся хранить вершины (как массив объектов, например) то у вас естественным образом возникает неупорядоченная нумерация (№ элемента в этом массиве).